# Handler fails to deliver a message or a Runnable to the main thread

Tags: android, user-interface, multithreading

I have an app with a two threads - main and data loader. When data loader finishes it posts a Runnable object to the main thread (as described in the DevGuide), but it never gets delivered and run.

Here's the basic code:

```
class MyApp extends Application
{
   public void onCreate()
   {
         LoaderThread t = new LoaderThread();
         t.start();
   }

   private class LoaderThread extends Thread
   {
        public void run()
        {
             SystemClock.sleep(2000);
             boolean res = m_handler.post(m_runnable);
             if(res)
                Log.d(TAG, "Posted Runnable");
        }
   }

   private final Handler m_handler = new Handler();
   private final Runnable m_runnable = new Runnable() {
             public void run()
             {
                 Log.d(TAG, "Hey, i'm runnable!");
             }
        }
}
```

Also it maybe important to note that I ran this code as a unit-test derived from an ApplicationTestCase:

```
class MyAppTest : public ApplicationTestCase
{
     public MyAppTest()
     {
          super(MyApp.class);
     }

     public void testLoading()
     {
          createApplication();
          // few asserts follow here...
     }
}
```

So this fails. Runnable never gets run() called, although the log indicates that it has been posted successfully.
I also tried to send simple messages instead of posting runnable (m_handler.sendEmptyMessage(1) for example) - they never get delivered to handler's callback in the main thread.

What do I miss here?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Handler` requires a [`Looper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) in order to work.  The `Looper` provides a message queue required by the `Handler`.

All instances of `Activity` have a `Looper` as one is used to process UI Events, but you can create your instance of `Looper` elsewhere.

Have a look in your Log output to see if Android is complaining about the absence of a `Looper`.

If it is, you might be able to fix by add the following to the top of your `onCreate()` method:

```
Looper.prepare(); 
m_handler = new Handler();
Looper.run();
```

And remove the initialisation of `m_handler` from later in your code.

Comment: I thought so to, but the Looper is created indeed. Because when I try to create it by myself (including trying your suggestion above) I get:

"java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread"

Also I just found that the code (unchanged) works fine when ran inside a full blown app in OS. On the other hand, when I run it as a test case it fails to work...

Any hints?
Looper is ok, it is not null, no exceptions, no errors in log. I'm puzzled.

Comment: Thanks for this hint! My code was not within an Activity and therefore not within a Looper...
I was trying to figure out why the messages sent over the handler are only delivered when the calling thread is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

`Handler` only works in an `Activity` AFAIK. You are attempting to use it in an `Application`.

Comment: I just found that this very code works when run as an application in OS, but fails when running as a test... So I guess this is something else missing. maybe related to activity...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to calling `Looper.prepare()` is to call `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`. The problem with calling `Looper.prepare()` is that it will throw an exception when there is already a looper on your thread. Chances are you are writing code that has to run under different environments and this solution will handle more cases.

See:
[AsyncTask and Looper.prepare() error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187960/asynctask-and-looper-prepare-error/4217754#4217754)