# AsyncTask and Looper.prepare() error

Tags: android, android-asynctask, looper

I have the following code

```
class OverlayTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {

        if (sites != null) {
            myMapView.getOverlays().remove(sites);
            myMapView.invalidate();
            sites = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            grabShipsWithLocation();
            return (null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        myMapView.getOverlays().add(sites);
        myMapView.invalidate();
        isLoading = false;
    }
}
```

That seems to work fine on a few test devices but I am seeing a lot of errors appearing on the dev console.  I can't seem to work out why and where to put this Looper.prepare().  Is it needed?

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.test.appname.FinderMain$1.gotLocation(FinderMain.java:286)
at com.test.appname.MyLocation$GetLastLocation.run(MyLocation.java:89)
at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:289)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
at android.os.AsyncTask.<clinit>(AsyncTask.java:152)
```

As requested MyLocation.java

```
    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
         lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

         Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
         if(gps_enabled)
             gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
         if(network_enabled)
             net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

         //if there are both values use the latest one
         if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
             if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
             else
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
             return;
         }

         if(gps_loc!=null){
             locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc); //Line 89
             return;
         }
         if(net_loc!=null){
             locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
             return;
         }
         locationResult.gotLocation(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does grabShipsWithLocation() do?

Comment: What line is MyLocation.java:89? add a comment to your source.

Comment: Are you creating/starting the AsyncTask from the main thread?

Comment: Please add the `gotLocation()` method or at least the snippet which initializes the `OverlayTask` class.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

**Long story:**

`AsyncTask` internally uses a `Handler`. A handler basically allows you to post `Runnables` from another thread on the thread the handler was assigned to, which in the case of `AsyncTask` is always the thread from which it is called. This only works for threads that have a `Looper` prepared, though.

For more information see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

**Short story:**

Simply wrap every call to `FinderMain$1.gotLocation` or the creation of `AsyncTask` within it in a `Runnable`, and post it to a `Handler` bound to the UI thread, like this:

```
class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override
    public void run() {
       // ...
       mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              locationResult.gotLocation(null);
          }
       });
       // ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Just the               locationResult.gotLocation(null); in the new section or the whole lot above?

Comment: Or each locationResult.gotLocation(stuff) ??

Comment: All calls to gotLocation need to happen within the UI Thread, meaning in the Runnable as above. You can also wrap the whole section within it, but keep in mind that this might slow down your UI, if its execution takes too long. Alternatively, you can also wrap the AsyncTask creation within gotLocation in a Runnable like this.

Comment: That seems to work and I published an update, however when trying to wrap the  locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc); it wants me to declare net_loc as final which then breaks the calls above it

Comment: Define net_loc as a member of GetLastLocation, or make it final and only assign it null in the else block of the initial if-clause, and not within the declaration

Answer (score 18):

I tried this...It worked,hope it will help you..

```
protected class Asyctast extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer>
{

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Log.d("Asynctask", ""+params);  
Looper.prepare();   

         ImageThumbnailsActivity m = new ImageThumbnailsActivity();

            Toast.makeText(ImageThumbnailsActivity.this,""+params ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            final Dialog dialog_options = new Dialog(ImageThumbnailsActivity.this);
            dialog_options.setContentView(R.layout.option);
            dialog_options.show();
        Looper.loop();
        return null;
    }       
}
```

Comment: It is a not good solution, cause Looper.loop() will blocked forever and Thread will never done. You should to use Looper.myLooper().quit() to avoid this.

Except of that if you need to call Looper.prepare() from Thread - use Thread instead of AsyncTask.