# Android: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to run the following but am getting the error

> Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Here is my code

```
private static void getLocations()
{   
    try
    {       
        m_locationManager = (LocationManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);           
        m_locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
            {
                Log.d("Output", "onLocationChanged");
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
            {
                Log.d("Output", "onStatusChanged");
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
            {
                Log.d("Output", "onProviderEnabled");
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
            {
                Log.d("Output", "onProviderDisabled");
            }
        };

        m_locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 1000, m_locationListener);
        Log.d("Output", "done");

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.d("Output", ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

If I put `Looper.prepare()` before the `requestLocationUpdates()` the error goes away but no events are fired.

If I then put `Looper.loop()` after the the `requestLocationUpdates()` it pauses and the "done" log is not called.

If if call the function within `runOnUiThread` like so:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() 
    {
        getLocations(); 
    }
});
```

no events are fired.

Im running this as a plugin for the Unity game engine so I don't have direct access to the main thread.

I have tried running this code outside of Untiy and it runs fine.

I'm pretty stuck on this one so any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

---

Update:

So I'm now trying to retrieve the locations inside a separate Activity. However, the events are still not being called.

```
public class LocationActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener
{
    private LocationManager m_locationManager;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout content = new LinearLayout(this);
        content.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        content.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        content.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        TextView infoLabel = new TextView(this);
        infoLabel.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        infoLabel.setTextSize(20.0f);
        infoLabel.setText("Initializing...");
        content.addView(infoLabel);

        try
        {
            m_locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            String provider = null;

            if (m_locationManager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) 
            {
                provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ;
                Log.d("Unity", "Using GPS");
                m_locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 100, this);
            } 
            else if(m_locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) 
            {
                provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
                Log.d("Unity", "Using Netword");
                m_locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 100, this);
            } 
            else 
            {
                Log.d("Unity", "Provider Not available");
            }       
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d("Unity", "locatons error " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        setContentView(content);
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {
        Log.d("Unity", "UserLocation Lat:" + location.getLatitude() + " Long:" + location.getLongitude());
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
    {
        Log.d("Unity", "onStatusChanged");
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
    {
        Log.d("Unity", "onProviderEnabled");
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
    {
        Log.d("Unity", "onProviderDisabled");
    }
}
```

The view is opened correctly and and Both GPS and Network are available. Still no firing events

Im using these permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Do you have any view available?

Comment: also remove static from the getLocations method.

Comment: Ive now added a view, still no luck. See update. Thanks guys.

Comment: Events where never fired - You need to change location to get an event.

Comment: Have you tried the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187960/asynctask-and-looper-prepare-error/4217754#4217754

Answer (score 0):

Try `mView.post(new Runnable() { getLocations() };`