# Android Code Error

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AsyncTask and Looper.prepare() error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187960/asynctask-and-looper-prepare-error)

```
10-03 18:38:32.041: E/Trace(685): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:322)
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at com.example.annapurna.DisplayContri$CreateContribution.doInBackground(DisplayContri.java:95)
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at com.example.annapurna.DisplayContri$CreateContribution.doInBackground(DisplayContri.java:1)
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-03 18:39:30.731: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  ... 5 more
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685): Activity com.example.annapurna.DisplayContri has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4100b318 that was originally added here
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.annapurna.DisplayContri has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4100b318 that was originally added here
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at com.example.annapurna.DisplayContri$CreateContribution.onPreExecute(DisplayContri.java:82)
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at com.example.annapurna.DisplayContri$1.onClick(DisplayContri.java:60)
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-03 18:39:32.461: E/WindowManager(685):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 18:44:31.601: E/Trace(712): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:322)
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at com.example.annapurna.DisplayContri$CreateContribution.doInBackground(DisplayContri.java:95)
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at com.example.annapurna.DisplayContri$CreateContribution.doInBackground(DisplayContri.java:1)
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-03 18:50:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  ... 5 more
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712): Activity com.example.annapurna.DisplayContri has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4100a568 that was originally added here
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.annapurna.DisplayContri has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4100a568 that was originally added here
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at com.example.annapurna.DisplayContri$CreateContribution.onPreExecute(DisplayContri.java:82)
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at com.example.annapurna.DisplayContri$1.onClick(DisplayContri.java:60)
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-03 18:50:54.580: E/WindowManager(712):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 18:50:57.681: E/Trace(732): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Program code where error is occuring is given here-

```
 package com.example.annapurna;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class DisplayContri extends Activity {
    // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        EditText editText1;
        //EditText  text2;
       //EditText  text3;

        // url to create new product
        private static String url_create_product = "http://10.0.2.2/annapurna_connect/userold.php";

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_contri);


        //Edit text
        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        //text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        //text3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        //Create Button
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        //button click event
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Creating new Contribution entry in background thread
                new CreateContribution().execute("");

            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateContribution extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplayContri.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) 
        {

            String name = editText1.getText().toString();
            //String age = (text2.getText().toString());
            //String id = (text3.getText().toString());
            Toast toast2=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);//This is where the error shows  
             toast2.show(); 
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", age));
            //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Annapurna.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_display_contri, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void contributor(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Contributor.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

   }
```

there is a Jsonparsor.java class for connectivity. 
In above code, doInBackground method() is not executing, I have tested the application by adding toast, and i found that it is not entering into doInBackground method and executing till last end of preexecute()

Comment: any context, like when or where did it happen? code example?

Comment: if you are dealing with any mail applications so that check the path of attachment you are sending

Comment: From you log, sounds you are trying to [update the UI](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=Can't+create+handler+inside+thread+that+has+not+called+Looper.prepare()) (like showing Dialog etc or changing layout) from background thread like `doInBackground()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are creating the AsyncTask on a thread other than the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update UI from doInBackground() of your AsyncTask.

It can't be done.

Please make sure to remove if you have any Toast or any other updation you are trying to do from doInBackground() to UI.

Comment: Thank you so so so so much...

Comment: I was stuck in the same code from last three weeks. but now it is done finally. thnx again

Comment: No problem my friend.. I am happy it helped you. Now how about accepting this as the answer by clicking the tick mark to the left side of this answer :)