# start async task from onhandleintent

Tags: android, android-asynctask, worker

Should we start async task from within `onHandleIntent()` method of `IntentService`? I read that `onHandleIntent()` runs in `worker thread` so will it be safe to start `asyncTask` from there??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IntentService`s already are background-processes; there's no need to start an AsyncTask from there. <s>Also, starting an `AsyncTask` is 'safe' from anywhere;</s> it's a helper class that helps you multithread. Just make sure you don't manipulate `View`s in the `doInBackground()`-method of your AsyncTask if you use it in your Activity.

If you need to spawn multiple threads inside your IntentService, just use:

> > new Thread(Runnable r).start();

See an example at [How to run a Runnable thread in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android)

If you need to call some kind of callback, use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). For an example, see http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#handler

Comment: starting an `AsyncTask` is not safe from anywhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187960/asynctask-and-looper-prepare-error - it is intended to be started from the main thread only, might work if you start it inside `onHandleIntent` since that has a Looper

Comment: What if , I don't use asyncTask inside onHandleIntent()? will the code inside it still run in background?

Comment: @zapl, thanks for the comment. Raghav: just call the method you want to call; your UI won't freeze up as the IntentService runs in a different Thread. If for whatever reason you want to spawn multiple threads in your IntentService, just use new Thread(Runnable r).start(); see example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android

Comment: @Rookie , yes, AFAIK, I use a method to download a file directly inside `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` method. and it works fine in all the device and varius Operating systmes.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask class is used to provide a mechanism to do achieve multithreading, so your event thread wont get hanged, but as you are using service, you should not use, AsyncTask in the Service, instead you can use, threads, if some long running task is to executed, in the Service.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use a AsyncTask inside an IntentService, you can create a method in your AsyncTask that calls de doInBackGround and the onPostExecute. Something like this:

```
void executeFlowOnBackground(Params params) {
  onPostExecute(doInBackground(params));
}
```

In my case I did this because all App request were made by a class that extended the AsyncTask, and because of the implementation was difficulty to refactor the code.