# setTextViewText not working in IntentService

Tags: android, android-appwidget, intentservice, remoteview

The code here in onHandleIntent:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.mylayout);
views.setTextViewText(R.id.txtView1, "some string");
...
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
int id = bundle.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID);
AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
manager.updateAppWidget(id, views);
```

does not update the widget's TextView named txtView1. I've searched and searched, but it appears that everything I've done seems to match what I found.

Comment: Service runs in the background You cannot update ui from service directly. Use a handler

Comment: Yes, agreed. This is also why Toasts don't work. However, RemoteViews could be in another process. The answer by @Harshid almost works, but it updates all instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh, thank you all for your answers, unfortunately it was my mistake. In my onUpdate from my custom AppWidgetProvider, I was passing the wrong Id. I've switched it now to the proper Id, and each widget instance updates properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need Handler to update UI from worker thread.

You can take help from this tutorial
http://crodrigues.com/updating-the-ui-from-a-background-thread-on-android/

or alternatively you can use `Asynctask` if you don't want to get into thread and handler stuff.

`Asynctask` manages this stuff by itself and you can update UI in onPostExecute() method and so on..

You can read details about `asynctask` in developer android site of google.

Comment: [this stackoverflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491049/start-async-task-from-onhandleintent) might also help

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your textview in app widget development.

```
  RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.mylayout);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.txtView1, "some string");
    thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, WatchWidget.class);  
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
```

Comment: Thank you @Harshid, this gets me farther than before, however, it updates all instances at the same time.