# android how to use intent service with asyncktask

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to call a web service from my android app IntentService (onHandleIntent method) but as they said its not safe following this url [start async task from onhandleintent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491049/start-async-task-from-onhandleintent)
what is the best method to call a web service from onHandleIntent and getting data returned by the web service to use it?

```
    @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    try{

                getTransactions get=new getTransactions("0");
                get.execute(d1,d2);
    //Here in on postExecute i need to do something with the results

        }


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        writeToFile("Exception" + e + "\n");
    }

    MyReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: "I want to call a web service from my android app IntentService" - So just do it. There's no need for an `AsyncTask`, as `onHandleIntent()` already runs asynchronously.

Comment: Okay so how i can use the data returned by the web service? what is the similar of 'onPostExecute' method in this case??

Comment: One option is to use [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to broadcast the results back to your Activity, or wherever you need them.