# I cannot add an object in an ArrayList in doInBackground()

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask

Hi I am new to Android and I have a problem with using AsyncTask. I created an object called `KelimeKutuphane` and I want to add objects an ArrayList in doInBackground but some errors have occured:

```
06-24 00:50:09.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3880): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-24 00:50:09.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3880): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-24 00:50:09.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-24 00:50:09.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-24 00:50:09.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-24 00:50:09.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-24 00:50:09.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-24 00:50:09.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-24 00:50:09.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-24 00:50:09.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-24 00:50:09.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-24 00:50:09.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3880): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
06-24 00:50:09.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
06-24 00:50:09.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:772)
06-24 00:50:09.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at com.example.hangdeneme.KelimeKutuphane.<init>(KelimeKutuphane.java:30)
06-24 00:50:09.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at com.example.hangdeneme.AsyncTaskKutup.doInBackground(AsyncTaskKutup.java:87)
06-24 00:50:09.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at com.example.hangdeneme.AsyncTaskKutup.doInBackground(AsyncTaskKutup.java:1)
06-24 00:50:09.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-24 00:50:09.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3880):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-24 00:50:09.091: E/AndroidRuntime(3880):     ... 5 more
```

and This is the related part of my `AsyncTaskKutup.java` that I use for adding objects to an `ArrayList<KelimeKutuphane>`

```
public class AsyncTaskKutup extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<KelimeKutuphane>>  {

    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ArrayList<KelimeKutuphane> tumKelimeler;
    ArrayList<KelimeKutuphane> filtered;
    private static int BITKI = 0;
    private int kategoriNum;
    private int turdakiKelimeSayisi = 10;

    public AsyncTaskKutup(Context context){
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Loading...");

    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<KelimeKutuphane> doInBackground(String... arg0) {


        tumKelimeler = new ArrayList<KelimeKutuphane>();

            //I have lots of those in here and when I delete those, this error goes:
        tumKelimeler.add(new KelimeKutuphane("some text", BITKI, 1, "More Text"));



        kelimeHazirla();
        return filtered;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... arg1) { 


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<KelimeKutuphane> filtered){

        progressDialog.dismiss();


    }

    public void kelimeHazirla() {

        filtered = new ArrayList<KelimeKutuphane>();

        for(KelimeKutuphane kelime : tumKelimeler){

            if(kelime.getKelimeLevel() == 1 && filtered.size() < turdakiKelimeSayisi ){

                filtered.add(kelime);
                }


            }

        }
```

---

Problem was solved thanks to CommonsWare. I extended my object class with Activity class for some reason. Removing this extension solved the problem.

Comment: Your stack trace indicates that your problem is in the constructor for `KelimeKutuphane`. What are you doing there?

Comment: Thanks for that. I extended 'KelimeKutuphane' with 'Activity' class for something but I have just changed it and problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Your log says that your error is not about adding to ArrayList, but about AsyncTask

> > Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

As you know, AsyncTask internally uses a Handler. And and tbelhis causes issues in your case.
Please see the answer following link:

[AsyncTask and Looper.prepare() error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187960/asynctask-and-looper-prepare-error)